# foreach loop return a single result set instead of all result

Tags: php

I want to display the number of like and unlike a post has in a forum app. And this is how I create it.

```
<?php foreach ($votespost as $vp):?>
   <?php if($post->id == $vp->postId):?>
       <li><?=$vp->voteUp . ' Thumb up'?></li>
       <li><?=$vp->voteDown . ' Thumb down'?></li>
   <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

But to my surprise, it only displays the result of the last post likes and unlikes(meaning the rest are not shown) and I tried to put this inside a while loop and for loop but dont work as they hang the laptop.

The problem is in the template and not in the controller(so that is why am not showing the controller code)

The $votespost and $post(this is the post of each thread and that display fine) are from the controller class and I think they are working fine

```
public function viewThread(){
        if (isset($_GET['threadid'])){
            //$thread = $this->threadsTable->findById($_GET['threadid']);
            //$posts = $this->postsTable->find('threadId', $_GET['threadid']);

            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                if($post->id){
                    $votesPost = $this->votesTable->find('postId', $post->id);
                }
            }
        }

        $user = $this->authentication->getUser();

        $title = 'View Topic';
        return [
            'template' => 'viewforum.html.php',
            'title' => $title,
            'variables' => [
                //'thread' => $thread ?? null,
                //'posts' => $posts ?? null,
                'votespost' => $votesPost ?? null,
                //'user' => $user ?? null
            ]
        ];
    }
```

I have commented out those not useful

Comment: What is `$votespost`? Where do you assign that? Also what is `$post` and why don't you just do the comparison in the query?

Comment: I suspect you need to perform aggregation in your query. You need to supply more information as to how you are generating the variables in this code.

Comment: @Nick have done that and what is aggregation?

Comment: Aggregation refers to collecting together rows of data into one row. As an example if you had a table `votes` with columns `postid, voteup, votedown` (one row per vote), you might write `SELECT postid, SUM(voteup) AS upvotes, SUM(votedown) AS downvotes FROM votes GROUP BY postid` to get the total up and down votes for each post. See this demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e995393033dfea15a14ff857fc11926

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($votespost as $vp):?> <?php if($post->id == $vp->postId):?> <li><?=$vp->voteUp . ' Thumb up'?></li> <li><?=$vp->voteDown . ' Thumb down'?></li> <?php endif;?> <?php endforeach;?>. You have a foreach that iterates all the posts, but inside that you only output if the post id matches the vp postId. You're missing the else case
```

Comment: What I want to do is match all votes with their corresponding post $vp->postId = $post->id eg if post->id is 3, search for that 3 in vote table using the column postId